# How to change the cell value in a Data Grid when clicked on the cell

Tags: c#

I have created a Data Grid of 17 columns and 65520 rows for some application in form based application in c#.
when ever I click on any of the data grid cell its value should change from 0 to 1. I have gone through the definitions for below click event

```
private void datagridview1_contentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

where most of them were for specific cell, but for me the value should change from 0 to 1 in any cell when clicked in the range specified(within 17 columns and 65520 rows).Since I am new to C# coding and Please help me in resolving this.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page! - __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name! - Contentclick is picky: you actually need to hit the content, not empty space! MouseClick is recommended.
 -

Comment: Sorry for the Incomplete Question .I have created Winform .Created DataGridView using c# in Visual Studio
I have written the function Definition which was missing above.

 private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   {
            for (; ; )
            { 
                if (e.ColumnIndex != 0 && e.RowIndex != 1)
                {
                    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value != null)

                        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = 1;
                }
            }
        }

Comment: The function will work after removing the endless loop at the start and if there is a value in the cell already, as you coded.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Windows Forms, this can help you.
Because you only want to change the CellContentClick event. With this event its easy to change the value of it. This code change the cell value to 1:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = 1;
    }
```